# Why gain value for init.xavier_uniform_ is 1.414 in GAT model?

Tags: pytorch

I'm working with GAT model, and I found that many codes in GAT model, they are using xavier_uniform with gain value 1.414.

I wonder they use that specific value.

```
self.W = nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(size=(in_features, out_features)))
nn.init.xavier_uniform_(self.W.data, gain=1.414)
```

Answer (score 0):

`gain` is the the scaling factor in xavier uniform initialization.

`root(2)` is the recommended gain value for ReLU. So if you're using ReLU activation function, then it's better to use 1.41 as gain value for initialization. Read more [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.init.html).

```
gain = nn.init.calculate_gain('relu')
print(gain)

1.4142135623730951
```

> Since the non-linearity will affect the std dev of the activation, you might run into some issues, e.g. vanishing gradients. The gain with respect to the non-linearity should give you “good” statistics of your activations. -- [source](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/what-is-gain-value-in-nn-init-calculate-gain-nonlinearity-param-none-and-how-to-use-these-gain-number-and-why/28131)

Comment: That doesn't actually answer the underlying question...